# What is the best solution for hosting videos behind a paywall?

Tags: google-app-engine, video-streaming

I am putting together a little site run on Google App Engine (python27 + django + webapp2). The objective of the site is to serve paid for video tutorials, much like lynda.com.

I'm trying to find the best (and cheapest) way of keeping the videos behind a paywall. In other words a customer is only able to view the videos on my site and if they've paid a subscription.

I've considered simply putting them on GAE, however the recent price increases have made me reluctant to do so and I was wondering if there were any other solutions available?

Cheers,
J

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question. Paywall implementation is separate from hosting (GAE). You could implement a paywall through a login system, or even by simply setting your server to require authentication before it sends content. In this sense, no paywall system is cheaper than another. On the other hand, you can *host* your site in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate users: implement your own login system or [use OpenID (federated login)](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.